# Installing FxRuby on Windows

Tags: ruby, fxruby

Simple question: How to install FxRuby on windows.
I have installed ruby 1.9 using one click installer from http://rubyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open up command prompt and type: 
`gem install fxruby` 
It will then be installed and ready to use. To use it in your applications, just place:

```
require 'fox16'
```

at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.9.2 it is included in Windows package so no gem download needed.
It does not appear in the gem list though, buts it's there.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.6.20, installation can be performed using `gem install fxruby`:

[Release notes for 1.6.20](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=35590)